# ¿Como añadir 15 días a un campo DateField teniendo en cuenta el valor de un registro en otro modelo?

Tags: python, django, python-2.7, django-models, django-forms

Disculpenme si no fui tan claro en el titulo, la pregunta es un poco difícil de formular debido a que lo que quiero hacer es cargar un formulario con una fecha por defecto teniendo en cuenta la fecha de otro modelo, los modelos son los siguientes:

```
class Meeting(TimeStampedModel):
    date = models.DateField(default=timezone.now, verbose_name=_('Fecha'), null=False, blank=False)
    ...                                                                 

class Engagement(TimeStampedModel):
    meeting = models.ForeignKey(Meeting, verbose_name=_('Reunion'), null=False, blank=False)
    tracking_date = models.DateField(verbose_name=_('Fecha de Seguimiento'), null=False, blank=False)
```

para el formulario del modelo Engagement deseo que cargue por defecto la fecha de la reunión mas 15 días, resalto que el campo `meeting` lo estoy renderizando en el `form` con un input hidden y le paso el valor con el método `get_initial` desde la vista desde esta manera:

```
class EngagementCreateView(SuccessMessageMixin, UserRequiredMixin, CreateView):
    template_name = 'engagement/form/create_engagement.html'
    model = Engagement
    form_class = EngagementForm
    page_title = 'Crear Compromiso'
    success_message = 'Compromiso registrado exitosamente'

    def get_initial(self):
        return {
            "meeting": Meeting.objects.get(pk=self.kwargs['pk']) #toma el valor pk enviado por la url
        }
```

el `id` o `pk` de la reunión se envia por url:

```
url (r'^create_engagement/(?P<pk>[\w-]+)$', views.EngagementCreateView.as_view (), name='engagement.create'),
```

Comment: ¿Qué campo en especifico quieres cargar la fecha + 15 días?

Comment: Hola @GermanAlzate, en el campo `tracking_date` deseo cargar por defecto la fecha del modelo `Meeting` mas 15 días

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Prueba a usar el modulo python-dateutil

Tienes la documentacion [aqui](https://dateutil.readthedocs.io/en/stable/)

En el forms.py puedes poner algo como:

```
from dateutil.relativedelta import relativedelta

class EngagementForm(forms.ModelForm):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(EngagementForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        quinceDias = relativedelta(days=15)
        fechaReunion = self.fields['date']
        self.fields['tracking_date'].initial = fechaReunion+quinceDias
```